# Why isn't setState rebuilding the widget with diff input?

Tags: flutter

I have this code. What I want is that when I press the button, the map[food] increments by 1, this is the map displayed by the piechart, and I want the piechart to rerender with the new data. Ignore the toggle, I'm not using it right now.

This piechart is from a package, here's what I added to the dependencies if you want to check it out: `pie_chart: ^0.8.0` and [this is it](https://github.com/apgapg/pie_chart/tree/master/example).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pie_chart/pie_chart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool toggle = true;
  Map<String, double> dataMap = new Map();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Food", () => 5);
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Gas", () => 3);
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Transportation", () => 2);
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Games", () => 2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Pie Chart"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: toggle
              ? PieChart(
                  dataMap: dataMap,
                  legendFontColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
                  legendFontSize: 14.0,
                  legendFontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                  chartLegendSpacing: 32.0,
                  chartRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.7,
                  showChartValuesInPercentage: true,
                  showChartValues: true,
                  chartValuesColor: Colors.blueGrey[900].withOpacity(0.9),
                )
              : Text("Press FAB to show chart"),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: add,
        child: Icon(Icons.insert_chart),
      ),
    );
  }

  void togglePieChart() {
    setState(() {
      toggle = !toggle;
    });
  }

  void add(){
    setState(() {
      dataMap["Food"]++;
      debugPrint(dataMap["Food"].toString());
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the package itself. It does the percentage calculation only in `initState()` method which is called only when creating the instance of PieChart.
You can edit the package code itself and add these two lines in the `build` method of the class `_PieChartState`:

```
initLegends();
initValues();
```

Comment: Wow that fixed it, Thanks

Comment: yeah but remember that will work only when you compile it from your pc because the changes are made to the local copy of the package in your pc and not in the package itself.